# Facebook app is Public, but still gives error “App not setup”

Tags: wordpress, facebook, authentication

I've read all the related topics as tried every solution written here, but still getting the same error in my website.
I'm using oneall social plugin and everything is set as it should, but Facebook login app keeps showing the same error every time trying to login.
My website is games2play.net
I have no idea what else may be wrong.. Tried deleting and creating new app, but nothing's changed.
Adding some screenshots.
[Facebook login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOsEB.jpg)
[Login App setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ59F.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your app is still in development mode as per the first screenshot.

In the Facebook Developer portal, you have to go to the "App Review" tab, then flick the toggle for "Make [app] public?"

Comment: Yes. In App Review tab it's Public and the green button is on.
Pasting as it's written: "Your app is currently live and available to the public."

Comment: Then you most likely are looking at the wrong app in the dashboard. Make sure you are using the same app ID. If you are file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I don't think so, cause it's the only app I have. Ok I'll try to register this bug.
Many thanks for help!

Comment: @PovilasButkus: The client_id parameter in the login dialog call is the app id. client_id and app id **are** clearly different in those two screenshots you have shown. So, you **are** looking at the wrong app, resp. have the wrong app id set in your code somewhere.